# Pandas adds "\r" to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

## This boils down to a simpler problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384652/python-write-replaces-n-with-r-n-in-windows)

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   0        1
0  a  A\nB\nC
1  a  D\nE\nF
2  b  A\nB\nC
```

When I write it to a csv file then read it back, I expect to have the same dataframe. This is not the case:

```
In [2]: df.to_csv("out.csv")

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv("out.csv", index_col=0)

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   0            1
0  a  A\r\nB\r\nC
1  a  D\r\nE\r\nF
2  b  A\r\nB\r\nC
```

A `\r` character is added before each `\n`. Writing and reading it again, the same thing happens:

```
In [5]: df.to_csv("out.csv")

In [6]: df = pd.read_csv("out.csv", index_col=0)

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   0                1
0  a  A\r\r\nB\r\r\nC
1  a  D\r\r\nE\r\r\nF
2  b  A\r\r\nB\r\r\nC
```

How can I stop pandas from adding a `\r` character?

---

Edits:
Yes I am on windows.

---

`pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False)))` gives me the same dataframe, so the problem seems to be writing to a file

---

Passing an open file object in binary mode like this:

```
with open("out.csv", "wb") as file:
    df.to_csv(file)
```

results in:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-f31d52fb2ce3> in <module>()
      1 with open("out.csv", "wb") as file:
----> 2     df.to_csv(file)
      3

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, **kwds)
   1342                                      doublequote=doublequote,
   1343                                      escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 1344         formatter.save()
   1345
   1346         if path_or_buf is None:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py in save(self)
   1549
   1550             else:
-> 1551                 self._save()
   1552
   1553         finally:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py in _save(self)
   1636     def _save(self):
   1637
-> 1638         self._save_header()
   1639
   1640         nrows = len(self.data_index)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py in _save_header(self)
   1632
   1633         # write out the index label line
-> 1634         writer.writerow(encoded_labels)
   1635
   1636     def _save(self):

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

---

Using regular write does not help

```
In [1]: with open("out.csv", "w") as file:
   ...:     df.to_csv(file)
   ...:

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv("out.csv")

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   Unnamed: 0  0            1
0           0  a  A\r\nB\r\nC
1           1  a  D\r\nE\r\nF
2           2  b  A\r\nB\r\nC
```

---

My python version is `Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)`

---

I have determined that the problem is with `pandas.read_csv` and not `pandas.to_csv`

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   0        1
0  a  A\nB\nC
1  a  D\nE\nF
2  b  A\nB\nC

In [2]: df.to_csv("out.csv")

In [3]: with open("out.csv", "r") as file:
    ...:     s = file.read()
    ...:

In [4]: s  # Only to_csv has been used, no \r's!
Out[4]: ',0,1\n0,a,"A\nB\nC"\n1,a,"D\nE\nF"\n2,b,"A\nB\nC"\n'

In [5]: pd.read_csv("out.csv")  # Now the \r's come in
Out[5]:
   Unnamed: 0  0            1
0           0  a  A\r\nB\r\nC
1           1  a  D\r\nE\r\nF
2           2  b  A\r\nB\r\nC
```

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Try this: `f = open('out.csv', 'wb'); df.to_csv(f)`

Comment: Have you tried the `sep` parameter? `df = pd.read_csv("out.csv", sep='\r\r\n', index_col=0)`

Comment: `pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False)))` loads the same DataFrame for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: @ayhan Yeah, I think it's a windows problem - windows appends carriage returns to newlines (there's historical significance, but I'm not sure of what it is).

Comment: @OP, did you try passing an open file object in binary mode? See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383584/pandas-adds-r-to-csv-file#comment81719886_47383584).

Comment: I tried the same thing on Windows 10 and it still gives me the same DataFrame (versions 0.20.3 and 0.20.1 respectively). @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ can you reproduce?

Comment: I just tried this on Windows 10 using Python 2.7 and got the same DataFrame that I saved.

Comment: @ayhan Ah, I don't have my windows machine with me at the moment, so :( It's possible OP thinks they're using python3, when they're actually using python2. What happens if you try this on py2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As some have already said in comments above and on the post you have put in reference  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384652/python-write-replaces-n-with-r-n-in-windows), this is a typical windows issue when serializing newlines. The issue has been reported on pandas-dev github [#17365](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17365) as well.

Hopefully on Python3, you can specify the newline:

```
with open("out.csv", mode='w', newline='\n') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, sep=",", line_terminator='\n', encoding='utf-8')
```