# Python Write Replaces "\n" With "\r\n" in Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, read-write

After looking into my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383584/pandas-adds-r-to-csv-file), I found that it was caused by a simpler problem.

When I write `"\n"` to a file, I expect to read in `"\n"` from the file. This is not always the case in Windows.

```
In [1]: with open("out", "w") as file:
   ...:     file.write("\n")
   ...:

In [2]: with open("out", "r") as file:
   ...:     s = file.read()
   ...:

In [3]: s  # I expect "\n" and I get it
Out[3]: '\n'

In [4]: with open("out", "rb") as file:
   ...:     b = file.read()
   ...:

In [5]: b  # I expect b"\n"... Uh-oh
Out[5]: b'\r\n'

In [6]: with open("out", "wb") as file:
   ...:     file.write(b"\n")
   ...:

In [7]: with open("out", "r") as file:
   ...:     s = file.read()
   ...:

In [8]: s  # I expect "\n" and I get it
Out[8]: '\n'

In [9]: with open("out", "rb") as file:
   ...:     b = file.read()
   ...:

In [10]: b  # I expect b"\n" and I get it
Out[10]: b'\n'
```

In a more organized way:

```
| Method of Writing | Method of Reading | "\n" Turns Into |
|-------------------|-------------------|-----------------|
| "w"               | "r"               | "\n"            |
| "w"               | "rb"              | b"\r\n"         |
| "wb"              | "r"               | "\n"            |
| "wb"              | "rb"              | b"\n"           |
```

When I try this on my Linux virtual machine, it always returns \n. How can I do this in Windows?

**Edit:**
This is especially problematic with the pandas library, which appears to write `DataFrame`s to `csv` with `"w"` and read `csv`s with `"rb"`. See the question linked at the top for an example of this.

Comment: In text mode, Python replaces all line endings with the system default. Use binary mode and encode the strings yourself to use custom line endings.

Comment: Alternatively, specify the line endings when you open the file. This is probably a much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are using Python 3, you're in luck. When you open the file for writing, just specify `newline='\n'` to ensure that it writes `'\n'` instead of the system default, which is `\r\n` on Windows. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> When writing output to the stream, if `newline` is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep). If newline is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If `newline` is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string.

The reason that you think that you are "sometimes" seeing the two-character output is that when you open the file in binary mode, no conversion is done at all. Byte arrays are just displayed in ASCII whenever possible for your convenience. Don't think of them as real strings until they have been decoded. The binary output you show is the true contents of the file in all your examples.

When you open the file for reading in the default text mode, the `newline` parameter will work similarly to how it does for writing. By default all `\r\n` in the file will be converted to just `\n` after the characters  are decoded. This is very nice when your code travels between OSes but your files do not since you can use the exact same code that relies only on `\n`. If your files travel too, you should stick to the relatively portable `newline='\n'` for at least the output.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> *newline* controls how universal newlines mode works (it only applies to text mode). It can be `None`, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and `'\r\n'`. It works as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> - When writing output to the stream, if *newline* is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, `os.linesep`. If *newline* is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If *newline* is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string.

```
open(..., 'w', newline='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The encoding of files are usually system dependent. As above answers have mentioned, we can hardcode newline option to be '\n' if it works for us. But this method won't work when you are fetching files or data from cloud as they often have restricted access and parsed to lightweight portable file format. So the best way to remove the default binary or any other encoding is to use a `decode()` method with `file.read()` output for any encode data.
For Example, In your case

```py
In [1]: with open("out", "w") as file:
   ...:     file.write("\n")

In [q]: with open("out", "file permission") as file:
   ...:     s = file.read().decode()

#--------------------------- OR --------------------------c

In [q`]: with open(..., newline='delimiter of your choice') as file:
   ...:     s = file.read()
```